# How to get pin image using pinterest api in php?

Tags: php, api, pinterest

I have all the boards of logged in user and using pinterest api i am able to fetch the pins from given board but when it returns the json there is no image link, the image field return as null. So how to get image with oin content. Here is json retrieved.

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 400327854358866609 [link] => https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/400327854358866609/4837342446222323658/8737cad9ec4b46439289fbd4f22353f02255549d33a8999691d82b8642f42625 [url] => https://www.pinterest.com/pin/400327854358866609/ [creator] => [board] => [created_at] => [note] => Hello this is simple test [color] => [counts] => [media] => [attribution] => [image] => [metadata] => [original_link] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 400327854358814014 [link] => https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/400327854358814014/4837342446222323658/3f1103b8d1c97de21f913293ee6062f4122313c931b054764167e96745f64465 [url] => https://www.pinterest.com/pin/400327854358814014/ [creator] => [board] => [created_at] => [note] => 55 Awesome Men’s Tattoos | InkDoneRight We’ve collected 55 Awesome Different Mens Tattoo Designs to inspire you! We also have the meaning and symbolism behind the common men’s tattoo designs... [color] => [counts] => [media] => [attribution] => [image] => [metadata] => [original_link] => ) ) [page] => )
```

In above json image or media key has no values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "API explorer", and add the "image" field, one of the outputs is the URL of the original image.

> https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/BOARD_OWNER/BOARD_NAME/pins/?access_token=MY_TOKEN&fields=id%2Clink%2Cnote%2Curl%2Cattribution%2Cboard%2Ccolor%2Ccreated_at%2Ccreator%2Cimage%2Cmedia%2Cmetadata%2Coriginal_link%2Ccounts

Or using the JS SDK eg:

> PDK.request(thisRequest, {fields: 'id,note,link,url,image'}, thisCmd,
>   function( PDKdata){};

See my example here:

> [Example of using Pinterest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300504/example-of-using-pinterest-api)

Comment: The link for the example is broken. Can you fix the link?

Comment: Looks like the post has been deleted. JC